# How to eliminate duplicates from an Excel file trough openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, break

I have two excel columns, name and company, and I'm trying to figure out what's the easiest way to make sure to obtain as an output a list of tuples (name, company) without any duplicates

The following code seems correct to me but for some reason it's not working, probably because of some dumb error I can't seem to find.

```
updated = openpyxl.load_workbook('abc.xlsx')
u_wb = updated.get_sheet_by_name('SP_Table')
u_names = u_wb['F'] #column F is where the names are
u_company = u_wb['C'] #column C is where the company's name are
l=[]

for x in range(len(u_names)-1):
    i=x
    i+=1
    if u_company[x].value==None #in case a field is missing
        continue
    if i==len(u_names):
        break
    for z in l:
        r=(u_names[x].value, u_names[x].value)
        if r==z:
            continue
    else:
        t=(u_names[x].value, u_company[x].value)
        l.append(t)
print("Number of contacts:", len(l))
```

I don't get any error and the contact's count is actually reduced but only because of the `u_company[x].value==None` clause.
Any help or resource is appreciated

Comment: If you are already using pandas, it may be easier to load the excel sheet to a dataframe, remove the duplicates and save it again. The entire thing should not be more than 3 lines

Comment: If you are not using pandas and would like to stick with your approach: is the order important?

Comment: If not, then load all the names and companies to a list; now this question is not different than any other question on SO about how to remove duplicates from a list

Comment: Haven't though about using pandas, indeed it looks much easier and will try it now, meanwhile I'm still very curios why this wouldn't work...Thank you very much on the hint!

Comment: For this kind of thing pandas won't be faster but it is still a very useful library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition on which you're trying to ignore duplicates is not correct.

You are adding to the list couples of `(u_names[x].value, u_company[x].value)`. That is OK and makes sense. The problem is that you're checking if `(u_names[x].value, u_names[x].value)` is already in the list.

Apart from that, even if it was the same, you're simply doing nothing when you find a duplicate. Your else statement after the `for` will **always** execute! This is because else statement after a `for` loop happens when the loop came to conclusion without hitting a `break` statement. So, what you want to do is:

```py
for x in range(len(u_names)):
    if u_company[x].value==None #in case a field is missing
        continue

    r = (u_names[x].value, u_company[x].value)
    if r in l:
        continue
    else:
        l.append(t)

print("Number of contacts:", len(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl has a powerful API to make this kind of thing easy

```
contacts = set() # sets cannot contain duplicates

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=6, values_only=True):
    company = row[0]
    name = row[-1]
    if company: # adjust if necessary
        contacts.add((company, name))

print(len(contacts))
```

Depending on what you want to do with the contacts, you might want to use a different data structure such as a dictionary.